# Unable to add alias to webpack.config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, config, node-modules, create-react-app

I've created react app with create-react-app and I'm unable to add alias to resolve -> alias node in webpack.config.js located in node_modules/react-scripts/config:
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/_components' in 'c:\my-app\src\app'

```
alias: {
  '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
```

Probably missing smth simple... Here are webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once you use `create-react-app` the standard way to modify your webpack setting is to run `npm run eject` as stated [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) and not modify directly at node_modules as you are trying to.

to avoid the ejecting command you could use a helper lib [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) which simplifies the process for overriding some default webpack configurations.

nevertheless, `create-react-app` offers the option to point absolute paths through a jsconfig.json file like stated in the [docs reference](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports) which might suit you better:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```